# Reading SCSI Command Description Block in software

Tags: disassembly

I have made a hardware control interface for my vintage Yamaha CBX-D5 audio recording processor. using MIDI SysEx commands.I managed to find out most of it's inner workings. I programmed SysEx in Arduino to send over the MIDI bus. It works great and now is a stand-alone unit with effects.
You can find a video on youtube if you look for adriaanhendrik and then CBXD5

Now I also own a CBX-D3, which is a basic 4ch audio processor without effect section.
It uses a startup sequence of SCSI commands sent from the host computer, so that RAM is filled with the right code to make it work just like it's bigger brother (CBX-D5). That way I can fill this code in a Chip so it can be used in stand-alone mode
I would like to read from it's SCSI bus in a software solution. I mean there are expensive hardware solutions out there, but these are out of reach for me.. so there must be a way to intercept the startup Command structure being sent over the SCSI bus so I can program it in a ATMEGA328P chip or something.

Anyone out there that knows how to achieve that one? I do have Logic Audio Platinium that sends those SCSI commands, but don't know how to read and interpret SCSI Command Description Blocks. Maybe there is a way to intercept it on the MacBook Bronze that runs it..